# Google plus: get 'me'

Tags: python, google-api, google-plus, google-api-python-client

I've been trying to find any clear documentation that explains the flow of getting profile data (including email) of an authenticated and authorized user (starting from the point where I have his auth_token). I can't find it anywhere on google's dev site.

Is there a simple scenario of urls that I need to call with the auth token to get the profile info (including email)?

I don't care for the authentication/authorization portion -- I'm past that already.

I'm using python, but it doesn't really matter since I'm not looking for any particular framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make a [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) request with an access_token that grants the `email` [scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes).

You can [try a live example](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#try-it).

```
GET /plus/v1/people/me
Host: https://www.googleapis.com
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.cABDhy4M21HMayoAAABH5qlNLgr...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
    "kind": "plus#person",
    "id": "114233674199568482864",
    "displayName": "Abraham Williams",
    "emails": [
        {
            "value": "abraham@example.com",
            "type": "account"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```